# Chrome Extension: How To Execute content.js On Certain URLs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am new to Chrome Extensions and I unable to find how to inject content.js to a specific URL only? I want the user to give me a specific URL and then inject the content.js to that specific URL. As of right now, my content script is being injected in all URLs. I am guessing there is something wrong in my Manifest.json or background.js or both since I am not sure if I used the executeScript function correct.

Right now I am only designing my code to not inject content.js to google.com but once I know the solution to this problem then it would be designed to specific URLs. I would appreciate any help, thank you.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Chrome Extension",
  "description": "Test Chrome Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
   },
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting", "tabs"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "all_frames" : false,
      "matches": ["http://*/", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["contentscript.js"],
      "css": ["contentscript.css"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
   ],
  "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "/images/16x16.png",
        "32": "/images/32x32.png",
        "48": "/images/48x48.png",
        "128": "/images/128x128.png"
       }
    },
   "icons": {
      "16": "/images/16x16.png",
      "32": "/images/32x32.png",
      "48": "/images/48x48.png",
      "128": "/images/128x128.png"
    },
    "host_permissions": ["http://*/", "https://*/*"],
    "options_page": "options.html"
}
```

**background.js**

```
// keep track of the URL when user changes URL in current tab
try {
  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == "complete") {
      let testURL = new URL(tab.url);
      // not allowed to inject content.js on chrome://   
      // testing to see if my content.js will not be injected to google.com but it still is
      if (!testURL.origin.includes('chrome') && !tab.url.includes('google')) {
        if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
          chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            files: ['contentscript.js'],
            target: {tabId: tab.id}
          });
          console.log(testURL.hostname);
        }
      } else {
        console.log('Invalid URL onUpdated');
      } 
    }
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}

// when user changes to a different tab, get URL of that tab
try {
  chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
    getCurrentTab();
    
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}

function getCurrentTab() {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs => {
    let url = tabs[0].url;
    let tab_Id = tabs[0].id;
    try {
      let urlConstr = new URL(url);
      if (!urlConstr.origin.includes('chrome') && !url.includes('google')) {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
          files: ['contentscript.js'],
          target: {tabId: tab_Id}
        });
        console.log('changed content here');
      } else {
        console.log('chrome website or google.com, don't inject content.js nothing');
      }
    } catch(e) {
      console.log('ERROR HAPPENED - ' + e);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Remove `content_scripts` and `background` from manifest.json, remove background.js. Use [chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/) in your UI (e.g. in the popup).

Comment: But I need my background.js since I am storing other information for my extension which needs to be running in the background when the popup is closed. For instance, I have a timer working on my background.js. Would that still work?

Comment: The contents of background.js shown in your question won't be necessary. You can add other code for other purposes.